# Python PULP optimization - LpVariable across THREE factors?

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

Is it possible to create an LpVariable in Python PULP across three variables?

So far, I've had success using the combination of two variables - here's an example using the combination of Basketball Player and Basketball Position. The optimizer will choose combinations of players+positions that each one will play at to maximize points. (Subject to constraints that are not written below)

`decision_variable = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('PlayerPosition', (PlayerVar, PositionVar), lowBound = 0, upBound = 1, cat='Integer')`

My question is -- is it possible to add a THIRD variable that the optimizer can optimize across? For example, say I want to optimize for two separate games at the same time --- is there any way to update the above code with something to the effect of `(PlayerVar, PositionVar, GameVar)` instead of `(PlayerVar, PositionVar)`?

I haven't had success with this thus far, but I'm fairly new to PULP and certainly not an optimization expert, so maybe I'm just missing something.

Comment: See: https://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/CaseStudies/a_sudoku_problem.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  The indices can be arbitrarily dimensional.  You'll probably want to gin up a few convenience sets to make this easier to write your constraints, etc.  Here is an example for your 3-tuple index

```
import pulp


# SETS

players = {'Jordan', 'Abdul Jabar', 'Johnson'}
positions = {'FWD', 'CTR', 'GRD'}
games = {4,5,6}

# the full x-set
player_pos_game = {(player, pos, game)
                    for player in players
                    for pos in positions
                    for game in games}

# example of a convenience set you'll likely need for constraints...
# you'll likely want other to make your constraints
player_pos = {(player, pos) for player in players for pos in positions}


prob = pulp.LpProblem("game_assignments", sense=pulp.LpMinimize)

# VARS

assign = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("assign", player_pos_game, cat=pulp.LpBinary)

for t in assign:
    print(t)
```

##### Yields:

```
('Jordan', 'CTR', 4)
('Abdul Jabar', 'CTR', 5)
('Jordan', 'GRD', 4)
('Abdul Jabar', 'GRD', 5)
('Abdul Jabar', 'FWD', 6)
('Johnson', 'CTR', 4)
('Jordan', 'FWD', 5)
('Johnson', 'GRD', 4)
('Johnson', 'FWD', 5)
('Abdul Jabar', 'CTR', 4)
('Jordan', 'CTR', 6)
('Abdul Jabar', 'GRD', 4)
('Jordan', 'GRD', 6)
('Jordan', 'FWD', 4)
('Abdul Jabar', 'FWD', 5)
('Johnson', 'CTR', 6)
...
```

Comment: Side question (you don't have to answer this, of course) --- would you mind walking me through how a Big M optimization would work if I wanted to limit the total number of players chosen across the three games? Say I could only choose a maximum of 5 players total who would have to be used across each game.

I would need some form of binary variable for each player indicating if they were used in *any* game, and then limit the sum of all the binary variables to 5, but not quite sure how to set that up.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. Assuming the pool of possible players is, say, 200 players deep and not the 3 in the example above -- what I want to do is choose a *total* of 5 players to play across the 3 games. (Assume there are still only 3 possible positions, and that every player has a different projected points total for each of the 3 games). So only 3 players will be playing in any one particular game, but I can only choose 5 *total* players. There may be different combinations of that group of 5 that will play in each of the 3 games.

Comment: I've got an idea for you.  It is completely separate from this topic, though, so why don't you post it as a separate question.  You can link it to this one if that helps for background.  If you have made an attempt, include that code.  Tag it w/ `pulp` and I'll probably see it (or somebody else will for sure.)